# AWS API Gateway with proxy-integration by serverless.yml

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I'm wondering how to set API Gateway with proxy-integration by serverless.yml (the "Lambda proxy integration" switch)

[image: the proxy-integration switch]

In [serverless document](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#request-parameters), I can't find any description about this setting.

And this is my code:

```
functions:
  lambda_func:
    image: my_image
    timeout: 300
    environment:
      STAGE: ${self:provider.stage}
    events:
      - http:
          path: lambda_func
          method: post
          async: true
```

I have tried to add 'integration: lambda' to the events config, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I find the answer.

```
functions:
  lambda_func:
    image: my_image
    timeout: 300
    environment:
      STAGE: ${self:provider.stage}
    events:
      - http:
          path: lambda_func
          method: post
          async: true
          integration: lambda-proxy # have to add this line
```